# Dynamically change validation on browser MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm implementing a donation form and I have a `Donation` model with the field "Amount":

```
[Required]
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
[Range(36, 10000)]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

I also have it's validation set in the view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Payment.Amount)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Payment.Amount)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Payment.Amount)
</div>
```

Problem is that when the user selects a diffrent "Currency" in the webpage the minimum amount should be changed for some currencies.

What I tried to do is to change the `Input` attributes:

```
$("#Donation_Currency").change(function () {
    var curr = this.value;
    switch (curr) {
        case "USD":
            document.getElementById("Donation_Amount").setAttribute("data-val-range", "The field Amount must be between 36 and 10000.");
            document.getElementById("Donation_Amount").setAttribute("data-val-range-min", "36");
            break;
        case "ILS":
            document.getElementById("Donation_Amount").setAttribute("data-val-range", "The field Amount must be between 100 and 10000.");
            document.getElementById("Donation_Amount").setAttribute("data-val-range-min", "100");
            break;
        default:
    }
});
```

But even though I see that the input attributes changed I still see the old message appears.

I'm doing something wrong that's for sure but the question is:

**How do I change the validation of the field according to the value set in another field?**

Comment: Are you sure the message is coming from the client-side validation? It could be that the input is validated successfully on the client side, but when it hits the server, it returns back with the message because the range is still between 36 and 10000 on the server.

Comment: hi @srinivas.naik. It is when I look at the attributes of the input in the developer mode, more than that, I set it to a bigger value then what it was (100 instead of 36) - so the lower minimum value on the server remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"But even though I see that the input attributes changed I still see the old message appears."*

That's because once the plugin is initialized, you **cannot** simply change the jQuery Validate options by changing HTML attributes (as you've learned).  Plugin initialization occurs *once* on page load and never again.

After initialization, you must use methods provided by the plugin to make dynamic changes to rules.  [See the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules) which dynamically adds rule(s)… it will *also* over-ride a previously defined rule.

Try something more like this…

```
$("#Donation_Currency").change(function () {
    var curr = this.value;
    switch (curr) {
        case "USD":
            $("#Donation_Amount").rules('add', {
                range: [36,10000],
                messages: {
                    range: "The field Amount must be between 36 and 10000."
                }
            });
            break;
        case "ILS":
            $("#Donation_Amount").rules('add', {
                range: [100,10000],
                messages: {
                    range: "The field Amount must be between 100 and 10000."
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried to do that but I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on the line with the .role(...)  (I user chrome) I dont know why but the .validation() functionality also doesnt work from the developer console - do you have an idea?

Comment: I solved the above commented error, now It's working - Thanks!